# Cosmos DB Emulator: "'analyticalStorageTtl' is not a valid property in the current payload" when AnalyticalStoreTimeToLiveInSeconds is set

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When using the .NET Standard SDK with the Emulator (v2.11.5.0) and trying to create a Container with the `AnalyticalStoreTimeToLiveInSeconds` set on the `ContainerProperties` object, the following exception is thrown:

`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: c4b8a5d2-29e3-4720-918c-123eb10da0a4; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid - 'analyticalStorageTtl' is not a valid property in the current payload."]}`

`ActivityId: c4b8a5d2-29e3-4720-918c-123eb10da0a4, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Please see CosmosDiagnostics, Windows/10.0.18362 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.11.4);'`

There is no error when using cloud hosted CosmosDB, only when using the emulator. Internet searches yield nothing about this, anyone have any ideas?

## Code to reproduce

### Program.cs:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string databaseName = "TestDatabase";
            const string containerName = "TestContainer";

            var accountEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
            var authKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";

            var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(accountEndpoint, authKey);
            await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName, 400);
            var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);

            await database.CreateContainerAsync(new ContainerProperties
            {
                Id = containerName,
                PartitionKeyPath = "/id",
                AnalyticalStoreTimeToLiveInSeconds = 0 // Removing this line makes the exception go away
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### ConsoleApp2.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You can't do any analytics in this emulator. Analytical Store is not supported in the Cosmos emulator. It only emulates the OLTP store for Cosmos.

Comment: Fair enough, but to save one from having to customize container creation code depending on whether or not they're using the emulator, would it not be better for it to simply ignore the property rather than it throwing an exception like it does at the moment?

Comment: The emulator is designed for dev/test of data plane operations, not DevOps. If you're creating a new container you should use an ARM template and/or PS/CLI and deploy via Azure DevOps rather than doing it in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As per Mark Brown's comments, the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator doesn't support Analytical Store and thus does not allow containers created with the setting and thus this error occurs.

Additionally, Microsoft does not really intend the SDK to be used for creating/updating containers for DevOps scenarios and hence is not looking to change the emulator's behaviour here.

For our project where the developers are using the emulator for local testing on their machines, as a short term solution we're using a appsetting to control this.

Long term we will be looking to handle the container creation as part of a deploy pipeline with scripting.